# How to specify a size for google pie charts?

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization, data-visualization, pie-chart

I'm having trouble changing the size of a google pie chart that I have made. I'm trying to draw multiple pie charts with the size of each chart proportional to the total amount of data that I'm feeding it. I am aware that we are able to change the size of the div container of the chart by adding options to the chart like as follows:

```
var options = {width: 400, height: 300};
```

However, what I'm interested in, is not changing the size of the `div`, but of the actual pie chart itself.

Is there any way I can change the radius of the pie chart?

I've searched around and wasn't able to find anything. Here is quick paint of what I mean:

[image: Example]

As you can see, what I would like is for the `div` to remain on the same size but the size of the circle to change, depending on what value I feed it.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try the [option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options) for `chartArea`

e.g.

`chartArea: {width: 400, height: 300}`

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply, somehow I don't get notifications for these replies. This isn't exactly what I was looking for (I wanted to specifically set a radius for the circle). chartArea makes the size of the pie chart reliant on the area surrounding it. I settled for this solution though, since it did help me make the pies differently sized, while being able to keep the divs the same width and height. Thank you!!

Answer (score 7):

Try the example as below 
http://jsfiddle.net/toddlevy/c59HH/

```
function initChart() {
var options = {
    legend:'none',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    pieSliceText: 'percentage',
    colors: ['#0598d8', '#f97263'],
    chartArea: {
        left: "3%",
        top: "3%",
        height: "94%",
        width: "94%"
    }
};
```

Comment: Excelent. Many thanks! Question: where did you find the docs for the chart area and legend ? I'd bee looking for these